# Incomplete Type is not allowed, 2 structs

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I know there are about a million of these posts, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Is it because elua_adc_ch_state is defined above then used again? The lines that err are marked.

```
typedef struct 
{
  // Status Bit Flags
  volatile u8     op_pending: 1, // Is there a pending conversion?
                  blocking: 1, // Are we in blocking or non-blocking mode? (0 - blocking, 1 - nonblocking)
                  freerunning: 1, // If true, we don't stop when we've acquired the requested number of samples
                  smooth_ready: 1, // Has smoothing filter warmed up (i.e. smoothlen samples collected)
                  value_fresh: 1; // Whether the value pointed to by value_ptr is fresh

  unsigned        id;

  u8              logsmoothlen;
  volatile u16    smoothidx;
  volatile u32    smoothsum;
  u16             *smoothbuf;

  volatile u16    reqsamples;
  volatile u16    *value_ptr;
} elua_adc_ch_state;

typedef struct
{
  elua_adc_ch_state   *ch_state[ NUM_ADC ]; *** <----
  volatile u16        sample_buf[ NUM_ADC ]; *** <----
  volatile u8         clocked: 1,
                      force_reseq: 1,
                      skip_cycle: 1,
                      running: 1; // Whether or not sequence is running
  volatile u32        ch_active; // bits represent whether channel should be converted on this device
  volatile u32        last_ch_active; // keep copy of old configuration
  unsigned            timer_id, seq_id; // Timer bound to device, sequencer device id
  volatile u8         seq_ctr, seq_len;
} elua_adc_dev_state;
```

All of the u16, u8, NUM_ADC assignments are defined and included. I'm just not sure why the second struct fails when the first is fine... No circular header dependencies either.

Thanks

Comment: If those are the only two lines with errors, then it's probably something wrong with `NUM_ADC`. How exactly is it defined?

Comment: its defined as zero, I also replaced NUM_ADC with a 0 and it is still throwing an incomplete type error.

Comment: You can't have arrays of length 0 in C.

Comment: @Mgetz, Changing the value to 1 fixes the incomplete type error, but shouldn't there be a better way to fix that? It compiles fine on my other GNU toolchain.

Comment: @Blackdragon1400 VLAs work by allocating memory AFTER the structure directly in most cases, they are a large case of UB in many cases. Also don't assume that GNU C is valid anywhere else.

Comment: @Mgetz No. An array cannot have length zero in standard C period. Your link to variable-length arrays show confusion, because “at the end of a structure” applies to incomplete arrays. Zero is an invalid length for both VLA and incomplete array: the length of a VLA must not be zero at run-time and an incomplete array does not have length zero, it has an unknown length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the issue is the <strike>variable length arrays</strike> flexible array members at the top of the structure, which are not really portable. The rules on <strike>VLAs</strike> Flexible Array Members require (§6.7.2.1p3) they be at the **end** of the structure definition:

```
typedef struct{
   int foo;
   unsigned int bar;
   int foobar []
} barfoo;
```

I would highly recommend not using <strike>VLAs</strike> flexible array members as they only exist in ANSI C99 and are [<strike>optional</strike> in ISO C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) <strike>(see §6.10.8.3)</strike> which is implemented more widely. <strike>The ANSI standard does not even seem to specify behavior for using VLAs in structures in C11 so it's probably undefined behavior.</strike>

#### Update:

Per Casey's comment below they are defined as *flexible array members* [(§6.7.2.1p18)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) however they do have many cases of undefined behavior (§6.7.2.1p21) even in the standard and should be avoided.

Comment: C11 is implemented _more widely_ than C99?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I probably should have said _will_ be but yes, more compiler writers have chosen to implement C11 mostly because it's largely C99 (with a few sections marked optional). So GCC technically already implemented it.

Comment: There are no VLAs in structures. There are *flexible array members*  defined in §6.7.2.1p18 which are arrays of zero size.

Comment: @Casey I have them (thanks for the section number) as [§6.7.2.1p16-18](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and it doesn't change the fact that there is a ton of UB around them.

Comment: @Mgetz 1256 is a bit long in the tooth, [N1570 is the last public pre-C11 draft.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) But yes, I too avoid them like the plague.

Comment: Flexible array members are a way to **avoid** undefined behavior, not a source of undefined behavior, that I know of. See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/31/From-Pascal-strings-to-Python-tuples (not an independent confirmation because written by me, but my colleagues and I went to the trouble of writing a static analyzer that detects undefined behavior in Python so we're not just throwing words around either). What undefined behaviors do flexible array members have “many case of”?

Comment: **An array with incomplete type is not array with size zero.**

Comment: Incomplete array are **not optional** in C11 (again, you are confusing them with variable length arrays). Please refer to specific standard clauses instead of throwing lies around peppers with “very clear” and “many”.

Comment: “As for your comment about 0 length arrays, that depends on which draft” Arrays of size zero were never allowed in any revision of the C standard. They are not part of standard C.

Comment: Your question still claims that §6.10.8.3 in C11 makes flexible array members optional. It does not. There is just one page, read it. `foobar [0]` is not how you declare an flexible array member. `int foobar[];` would be. Your recommendation for not using incomplete arrays is grounded only in your confusing them with something else.

Comment: @PascalCuoq fixed (I was actually confused about why you were going on about the zero thing). As for being optional... I think that requires clarification of the standard, you can't NOT have VLAs and have FAMs but I'll put a strike in it for now.

Comment: In C11, please see 6.7.6.2:1 (esp. “If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.”) and the entirety of 6.7.6.2:4. You can definitely have FAM, which are non-optional, and not VLA, which are optional, in a C11-compliant compiler.

Comment: @PascalCuoq so insofar as the array is a) declared in a structure, and b) declared using `[]` instead of `[*]` that works... wow that is narrow. It still constrains how you can use the parent type though significantly (hence my comment about UB §6.7.2.1:21).